# Java Jersey - Rest connections through a proxy

Tags: java, proxy, jersey

I developed an application in java that needs to consume a set of webservices provided by a provider.

Basically I need to call a first rest webservice to connect to the system, in which I pass username and password in the body of the post rest call.

Without using proxies I can make a second rest call without passing username and password, the webservice provider recognises me.

But when I use a proxy this second call does not work any more, I get an HTTP 401 error.

Notice that the first connect call works well also with the proxy.

Is there something conceptual that I'm missing? 
Anyone knows what is happening?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're making only a single *login* request and then making follow up requests which do not supply credentials, the service you are consuming probably is using cookies to track a user session.

When you put a proxy between yourself and that service, if the proxy is not forwarding all of your HTTP header information (where the cookie is probably being exchanged with the service), then the service will no longer recognize your session and consider you unauthorized

You may need to better understand how the service is maintaining your session (is it using `Set-Cookie` headers that it expects you to send back?)  And you need to understand if the proxy you are using is forwarding all of your headers to the service

Comment: Thank you, indeed the service is sending me some cookies.Should I check on the proxy to be sure it forwards me headers, or should I manage cookies via java?

Comment: You just have to make sure that your HTTP headers (i.e. cookies) are flowing all the way from your Java code, through the proxy, to the service, and all the way back.  Basically make sure your proxy is not inadvertently interfering  with your HTTP headers

Comment: Thank you, indeed it was a cookie issue, setting the cookies solved the problems. But I still have some doubts, why the service accepts my second call when I don't pass through the proxy and I don't pass any cookies?

Comment: The client you're using may be doing it automatically in one case, and not the other?  Many HTTP clients transparently manage cookies for you, perhaps once it's configured with a proxy the behavior changes